# how to call custom serializers in sinatra application

Tags: ruby, json, activerecord, serialization, sinatra

I am working on a backend of an application written in Sinatra.
It has a route "/notifications"

which renders all the notifications in JSON.
I want to change the json structure and wrote some custom serializer and it is failing now.
the error i get is

```
"{"message":"undefined method  `read_attribute_for_serialization' for nil:NilClass"}"
```

I have a file called webservice/notification.rb 
which selects a notification serializer.
the code is something like this

```
serializer = NotificationSerializer
json serialize(notifications, root: :notifications, each_serializer: serializer)
```

The NotificationSerializer is something like this.

```
class NotificationSerializer < Serializer
  attributes :id, :tag, :event, :time, :read

  has_one :reference, polymorphic: true, include: true
```

The reference here can be a lot of things.

the notification model defines reference as

```
  def reference
company || contact || deal || invitation || meeting || todo || reference_email || reference_user ||
contact_import_job
  end
```

now all of these models in reference have there Serializer implements in directory Serializer/*
I want to make custom Serializers for all of these which will render limited information.
how can I call my custom Serializer for things inside reference.

I wrote a custom serializer for notifications and called it like this inside my refernce function and it worked.

```
...|| UserNotificationSerializer.new(reference_user) || ...
```

but if i do the same for my other models i get the error given above.
what would be the correct way to call my custom serializers.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it is to write an instance method on the model:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def public_attributes # or call it whatever
    attributes_hash = attributes
    # in activerecord, the attributes method turns a model instance into a hash
    # do some modifications to the hash here
    return attributes_hash
  end
end
```

then say you're returning json in a controller:

```
get '/some_route' do
  @notifications = Notification.all # or whatever
  serialized_notifications = @notifications.map(&:public_attributes)
  # For a single record, you could do @notification.public_attributes
  json_data = serialized_notifications.to_json # a serialized array of hashes
  content_type :json
  return json_data
end
```